# How to get first 5 chars of a git commit hash id and store it in a variable in bash?

Tags: bash, git

```
${$(git rev-parse HEAD):0:5}
bash: ${$(git rev-parse HEAD):0:5}: bad substitution
```

`git rev-parse HEAD` returns the hash id, but how do I make a substring out of it?

if I divide it into two lines, it works.

```
x=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
echo ${x:0:5}
```

But How do I do it in one line?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using `--short` option:

```
$ git rev-parse --short=5 HEAD
90752

$ x=$(git rev-parse --short=5 HEAD)
$ printf '%s\n' "$x"
90752
```

Answer (score 3):

The cut utility should do what you want.

```
$ x=$(git rev-parse HEAD | cut -c1-5) && echo $x
```

Why one line?